# understanding java operator <<

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators

i was working through the following [oracle java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/examples/SynchronizedRGB.java) and came across this line of code:

```
public synchronized int getRGB() {
    return ((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue);
}
```

I am lost as to what "<<" means, I also don't know what the return statement is suppose to return

Comment: Please see the [Java Tutorial on "Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit shift operation. Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). It will pack these 3 numbers into one integer.

Comment: Bit shift not byte shift

Comment: I fixed "byte" vs. "bit" with my edit :)

Answer (score 2):

24 bit colors are often represented as RRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB, with 8 bit values for each color. Your code takes the red value, shifts it 16 bits, shifts the green value 8 bits, and keeps the blue value unshifted, then performs a logical OR, which in this case is the same as adding the values. Think of it this way:

Your byte values for each color:

```
Red = 00011010
Green = 10101010
Blue = 11111111
```

The shifted values become:

```
Red << 16 = 
00011010 00000000 00000000
Green << 8 = 
00000000 10101010 00000000
Blue = 
00000000 00000000 11111111
```

The logical OR combines them into:

```
00011010 10101010 11111111
```

which is your 24 bit RGB value, which is returned.

Comment: I like your answer better than mine, +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
public synchronized int getRGB() {
   return ((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue);
}
```

> I am lost as to what "<<" means, I also don't know what the return statement is suppose to return?

First off, the '<<' is called a *bit shift operator*.  There is a fantastic write-up about them located [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html).

As to your second question, look at the signature of the method... it's going to return an `int`.  BUT, in this case, it is going to return and `int` containing the value of `blue` and the *bit shifted values* of `red` and `green`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`x << y` means "shift binary representation of `x` to left `y` places"

For instance

```
System.out.println(4 << 2);
```

will print `16`.

`4` is `100` in binary. If you shift `100` to the left 2 places, you get `10000` which is `16` in decimal.